# localStorage not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

I am able to successfully store the data in localStorage from a `form` input and display it down the `form` input. But each time I input some new query and press the `submit` button it is showing me updated value without the previous searches. How can I display all the previous searches and store the values so that even after page is refreshed my search queries are stored? Do I need to store it in some array or is there any other method in `localStorage`? My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function clickCounter()
  {
   if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
     {
      localStorage.formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
      document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = localStorage.formInput;
     }
   else
    {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type='text' id='theInput' value='Write here' />
 <input type='button' onclick='clickCounter()' value='See what you wrote'/>
 <div id="result"></div>
  <p>You wrote: <span id='newText'></span> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you store stuff in local storage? *What* do you store? How exactly do you expect your code to work?

Comment: Make if (typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") if (Storage)

Comment: @Pointy I guess my question is pretty clear and it has the answer of your questions

Comment: Whoever is putting a down vote - what else do you expect a question should contain?

Comment: No, it's not clear at all.  You didn't post any code that **stores** anything to local storage. In fact what you posted has nothing to do with local storage at all.

Answer (score 3):

In order to properly store information in localStorage you have to assign it a key. What you are doing is simply storing the values in Javascript's memory, which does not persist across page refreshes. Also be aware that the page will only get the value of your locaStorage key when clickCounter() is run. So it will not be placed on the apge at page load, unless you initialize the function on page load.

You'd want to do something like this:

```
function clickCounter()
  {
   if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
     {
      localStorage.formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
      document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = localStorage.formInput;
     }
   else
    {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
 }
```

Please be aware the localStorage is implemented differently across different devices and browsers. You may also want to investigate Modernizr for feature detection. Please also be aware that in some browsers, (Chrome) that if the user clears the cookies, localStorage is also cleared.

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: What is Storage for you? Did you incorporate Modernizr as I suggested?  My hunch is that Storage is an undefined variable and not your localStorage cache.